# Searching a connector for a test port on a router

Tags: serial, connector

I have a bunch of Teltonika RUT500 Routers which have a test connector on board which expose a serial console.

[image: Image of Connector]

While I has able to access the serial port by soldering a connector to the contacts, I am now searching a suitable connector for the contacts. I have measured the pins an they are 1,27mm apart.

A PCI Connector may fit if cutted into the right size, but I wonder if theres another more fitting connector available.

Comment: If you want to do a one-time access to a bunch of boards, the cut-down piece of card edge connector sounds good.  If that is precarious and you want to repeatedly access them, I'd find a 1.27mm header you could solder to each board and use with a mating cable.  Finding such is as much determined by what you can easily buy and work with as by what it theoretically made, so I'd start with a prototype-quantity distributor's online parametric search.

Comment: For my 2-3 test devices I have used a 2,5mm TRS connector and wired the serial interface to this. But from time to time I get some returned devices, where it is very helpful to check first via serial console if the unit is defective or just wrong configured. For this a temporary connector would be more feasible..

Comment: You could do something with a fixture with pogo pins, but I suspect the card edge connector may be simpler if it fits.  If you get console/boot message output without any input, then you might even be able to recover this by simply holding a single "probe" on the outgoing signal and getting the return ground through the power supply connection which appears to be immediately adjacent.